# Method of spherical means/average

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

These are a few steps I don't understand from my partial differential equations course. Let us be in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The average of a function $u(x,t)$ on the sphere $||x||=r$ of center $0$ and radius $r$ is denoted $\overline{u}(r,t) = \frac{1}{4\pi r^2} \int\int_{||x||=r} u(x,t) dS$.

My first question is, why is $\overline{u}(r,t) = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}u(x,t) \sin (\theta) d \theta d \phi$? I know that we are changing to spherical coordinates, but I'm not sure about the intermediate details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the integral
$$
\overline{u}(r,t) = \frac{1}{4\pi r^2} \int\int_{||x||=r} u(x,t) dS
$$
the area in the spharical polar coordinates is element $dS = r^2\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi$, where $0\le \theta \le \pi$ and $0 \le \phi \le 2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how would your second comment imply $\Delta \overline{u} = \overline{\Delta u}$?

Comment: I should have written "it might help to use it", but I don't know yet! I think you removed that part from the question

Comment: I moved it to a different question : )